# Why does the linker failed to find tcl/tk?

Tags: ubuntu, tcl, d, tk-toolkit

I am testing an official **tcl/tk** sample in **d language**, but it fails at linking step. I am on **Linux Mint 19 Cinamon 64bit**, and I have installed at least

- libtcl8.6
- libtk8.6

Also, I am using **DUB version 1.14.0**, built on Apr  5 2019

I went to the tk binding page and followed steps for Linux : [binding page](http://code.dlang.org/packages/tkd) :

1. installation of tck/tk 8.6 libraries
2. usage of code sample

```
...

class Application : TkdApplication                       // Extend TkdApplication.
{
    private void exitCommand(CommandArgs args)           // Create a callback.
    {
        this.exit();                                     // Exit the application.
    }

    override protected void initInterface()              // Initialise user interface.
    {
        auto frame = new Frame(2, ReliefStyle.groove)    // Create a frame.
            .pack(10);                                   // Place the frame.

        auto label = new Label(frame, "Hello World!")    // Create a label.
            .pack(10);                                   // Place the label.

        auto exitButton = new Button(frame, "Exit")      // Create a button.
            .setCommand(&this.exitCommand)               // Use the callback.
            .pack(10);                                   // Place the button.
    }
}

...
```

The compilation output

```sh
$ dub
Performing "debug" build using /usr/bin/dmd for x86_64.
x11 1.0.21: target for configuration "tcltk-import" is up to date.
tcltk 8.6.5: target for configuration "library" is up to date.
tkd 1.1.10: target for configuration "library" is up to date.
hello-user ~master: building configuration "application"...
Linking...
/usr/bin/ld : ne peut trouver -ltcl
/usr/bin/ld : ne peut trouver -ltk
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error: linker exited with status 1
/usr/bin/dmd failed with exit code 1.
```

Where '*ne peut trouver*' means "**could not find**".

This is my dub.json

```
{
    "authors": [
        "laurent bernabe"
    ],
    "copyright": "Copyleft 2019, Laurent Bernabe",
    "description": "Simple user greeting",
    "license": "MIT",
    "name": "hello-user",
    "dependencies": {
        "tkd": "~>1.1.10"
    },
    "postGenerateCommands-windows-x86": [
        "copy $TCLTK_PACKAGE_DIR\\dist\\x86\\tcl86t.dll build\\tcl86t.dll /y",
        "copy $TCLTK_PACKAGE_DIR\\dist\\x86\\tk86t.dll build\\tk86t.dll /y",
        "xcopy $TCLTK_PACKAGE_DIR\\dist\\library build\\library /i /e /y"
    ],
    "postGenerateCommands-windows-x86_64": [
        "copy $TCLTK_PACKAGE_DIR\\dist\\x86_64\\tcl86t.dll build\\tcl86t.dll /y",
        "copy $TCLTK_PACKAGE_DIR\\dist\\x86_64\\tk86t.dll build\\tk86t.dll /y",
        "xcopy $TCLTK_PACKAGE_DIR\\dist\\library build\\library /i /e /y"
    ]
}
```

Meanwhile, I've just found that both libtcl8.6.a and libtk8.6.a are under /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu. I've tried to set

```sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

but it did not work neither.

Comment: The link you mentioned is about DWT, which is SWT ported to D. DWT does not need TK, it depends on GTK... You should update the link to point to the TKD project instead.

Comment: @DejanLekic Thank you for having pointed me that : I edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed !!!

I created several soft links :

```sh
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcl8.6.a /usr/lib/libtcl.a
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtk8.6.a /usr/lib/libtk.a
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcl8.6.so /usr/lib/libtcl.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtk8.6.so /usr/lib/libtk.so
```

So that running `dub` compiles successfully.

Comment: So… use `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -ltk8.6 -ltcl8.6`?

Comment: Thank you. Indeed I am not yet used to the linker options : your solution is better.